# Looking for a function $f$ that solves $f'(x)= \alpha(x) f(x)$ for a continuous $\alpha$ and starts off positive but then turns negative

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a continuously differentiable function $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ (note that I don't care about the interval $[-1,1]$ in particular; it can be replaced by any interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ of your choice) that satisfies

- $f(t)>0$ for all $-1\le t<0$,
- $f(0)=0$,
- $f(t)<0$ for all $0<t\le 1$

as well as

$$f'(t)=\alpha(t) f(t)$$

for some **continuous** $\alpha:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$.

Essentially I am looking for something like this:

[image]

---

**My attempts:** The most obvious attempt is  $f(t)=-t^3$. However, one notices that we need to have $\alpha(t)=\frac{3}{t^2}$ for $t\not=0$, which *cannot* be extended to a continuous function. So $f(t)=t^3$ doesn't work.

In fact, if $f$ is any polynomial with $f(0)=0$, we know that $\frac{f'}{f}$ diverges at $0$ so that $\alpha=\frac{f'}f$ can't be continuous....

---

**Next try, $f(t)=-\exp\left(-\frac1t\right)$** for $t>0$ and $f(-t)=-f(t)$: This fails immediately as for $t\not=0$, $f'(t)=\frac{f(t)}{t^2}$, so that, once again, $\alpha(t)=\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}=\frac{1}{t^2}$ can't be made continuous at $t=0$.

---

**Final attempt:** I define $g(t)=2 \operatorname W(\exp(t))-t-1$, where $\operatorname W$ is the Lambert W function. This is a rotation of the function $t\mapsto\exp(t)$ by 45 degrees and it looks like this:

[image]

Then I define $$f(t)=\begin{cases}
g(t+1) & t\le 0,\\ -g(t+1) & t>0.
\end{cases}$$

It looks like this:
[image]

However, once again we have that $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$ is non-existant so that $\alpha$ can't be continuous at $0$.

---

**So my question:** Does a function $f$ as above even exist? If yes, can you give me an example? If not, why doesn't such a function exist??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that, $$F:[-1,1]\times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, (t,y)\mapsto \alpha(t)y$$ is Lipschitz-continuous in the second variable: For all $t\in[-1,1]$, $$|\alpha(t) y_1-\alpha(t)y_2|=\lvert\alpha(t)\rvert\cdot\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert \le\lVert\alpha\rVert_{L^\infty([-1,1])}\lvert y_1-y_2\rvert,$$

so that Picard-Lindelöf can immediately be applied to show that the only solution is $y\equiv 0$.

*Note:* I was so focused on the fact that the function $\alpha$ doesn't have to be Lipschitz continuous that I forgot that Lipschitz-continuity in $t$ isn't required...

Answer (score 4):

Any function that is solution will have the form $f(x) = f(0) \exp\left(\int_0^xa(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)$ and thus will have a constant sign (the sign of $f(0)$).
Moreover, because of Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem, any solution that is vanishing at zero will be vanishing everywhere. See "first order linear differential equation" or any related topic.

Comment: Ahhh you are right: I was totally blind and didn't see that $\alpha$ doesn't have to be Lipschitz-continuous for the RHS to be Lipschitz in $y$.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since $y=0$ is a solution, by the existence and uniqueness theorem, your equation only has zero solution. This is becasue the initial condition is $y(0)=0$.

Comment: Ahhh you are right: I was totally blind and didn't see that $\alpha$ doesn't have to be Lipschitz-continuous for the RHS to be Lipschitz in $y$.... Thanks!